# How to remove the saw tooth of UIView when using Quartz?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, quartz-graphics

I want to add a head button to a view with some white space around it. My code is just like this:

```
// head button
UIButton * btnHead = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnHead.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width - property.userhead_cell_space / 2, self.frame.size.width  - property.userhead_cell_space / 2);
btnHead.clipsToBounds = YES;
btnHead.layer.cornerRadius = btnHead.bounds.size.width / 2;
btnHead.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
btnHead.layer.borderWidth = (isPad?4.0f:2.0f);
btnHead.layer.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
btnHead.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

[btnHead addTarget:self action:@selector(clickHead:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self addSubview:btnHead];
```

But alway it has some saw tooth around it . It may only one pixel. But it looks very terrible . Just like this:
[image: The head button with black saw tooth around it]

Does anybody has some tip to remove the black saw tooth ?

Comment: instead of doing this with quartz core, why dont you just get the image converted to a circle with white border..

Comment: @lukya Because They alway change the size,border width and other property of the button. I should find some common method to complete this.

Comment: You can always do that using Core Graphics and overriding the button's drawRect. I've done similar things (using CG) and that "saw tooth" doesn't appear.

Comment: Why are you setting the content scale? You don't need to do that for view layers. Are your coordinates all even numbers, so you aren't using half sizes for your radius or frame?

Answer (score 0):

Way late to the party but from past experience this is a bug with corner radius and borders. I've tried using it to create circular borders around views and have noticed similar bleeding.

One workaround is to create a view for the border and then a slightly inset view for the image.

```
UIView* border = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
border.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor; // border color
border.layer.cornerRadius = border.bounds.size.width / 2;
border.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

// inset by the desired border width
UIImageView* image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(border.bounds, 2, 2)];
image.image = someImage;
image.layer.cornerRadius = image.bounds.size.width / 2;
image.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

[border addSubview:image];
[self addSubview:border];
```

If you want to avoid multiple views, you could add an additional background layer to the image view's layer for the border. That would need to have it's bounds negatively inset so that it drew around the image.